# Como fazer uma mascara no MS Access que funciona para telefones de 10 ou 11 dígitos?

Tags: microsoft-access

Gostaria de saber como fazer uma mascara que funcionasse para telefones de tanto 10 quanto 11 dígitos no Microsoft Access. Que ficaria:

(99) 1234-1234

(99) 12345-1234

Eu só sei usar as mascaras padrão, e as que tentei fazer o "-" sai no lugar errado para 10 dígitos (Ex.: (99) 12345-123).

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: poderia postar as suas tentativas ( "-" no lugar errado )?

Answer (score 2):

Coloque o seguinte script no comando aoSair do foco da caixa de texto

```
If isnull(Txttelefone) or TxtTelefone="" Then exit sub

Select case len(TxtTelefone)
Case 10 
    TxtTelefone=Format("00 0000-0000")
case 11
    TxtTelefone=Format("00 00000-0000")
case else
    msgbox "Preenchimento incorrecto."
docmd.cancelevent
end select
```

Acredito que irá funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

If isnull(Txttelefone) or TxtTelefone="" Then exit sub

Select case len(TxtTelefone)

Case 10

```
TxtTelefone=Format(TxtTelefone,"00 0000-0000")
```

case 11

```
TxtTelefone=Format(TxtTelefone,"00 00000-0000")
```

case else

```
msgbox "Preenchimento incorrecto."
```

docmd.cancelevent

end select

Assim dará certo com certeza

Answer (score -1):

Simples!

Nas propriedades dos campos, tanto de telefone fixo quento de celular, na coluna Tipos de dados selecione Texto curto e insira no campo máscara de entrada os seguintes formatos:

(99)9999-9999 para telefone fixo
(99)99999-9999 para celular.